# batch - How to return error when blank input on set /p

Tags: batch-file

I have a section of my batch file which prompts the end user to enter a case insensitive `Y` or `N` to continue.

But if I just press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the batch file quits.

I want it to return an error, when the person inputs blank or anything other than `y`/`Y`/`n`/`N`.

Here's my code:

[image]

Comment: just use an if statement to compare the variable (in quotes) with an empty set of quotes to detect an empty string.  But you might prefer to check for Y and N instead.

Comment: Simple answer, do not use `set /p` it is not the correct command to use in such scenarios. Use the built-in choice.exe utility instead. `%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /M "Start the heckerz show"`, `If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo loserrr`, and if the next line after your current `if`'s isn't already `:goodStuff`, `GoTo goodStuff`. With `choice` your end user can only enter one of the options. open a command Prompt window, type `choice /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information presented. The default options are a locale specific Yes/No character, so the `/C` option is not required.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Batch files are written in plain text, and there is absolutely no reason to be using an image for that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by simply adding

`if %errorLevel% == 1 goto loserrr2`

and

```
if not %heckerz% == y goto loserrr2
if not %heckerz% == n goto loserrr2
if not %heckerz% == Y goto loserrr2
if not %heckerz% == N goto loserrr2
```

thanks to Jerry Jeremiah for the help :D

and sorry for any error i commited on my question, as i said im new to Stack OverFlow

Comment: You should consider reading the help file for the commands you are trying to use. It will save you a lot of time and will reduce your code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `set /p` try using `choice`:

```
%windir%\System32\choice.exe /m "Start the heckerz show ?" /c YN
if %errorlevel%==1 goto goodStuff
if %errorlevel%==2 goto loserrr
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...
so maybe this is the answer:

```
:heckerz
@echo off
title Heckerz Tools
@echo Text
set /P "opcao=Start the heckerz show? (Y/N): "
if '%opcao%' equ 'y' goto goodStuff
if '%opcao%' equ 'n' goto loserrr
if '%opcao%' equ 'Y' goto goodStuff
if '%opcao%' equ 'N' goto loserrr
goto heckerz

:goodStuff
@echo Text 1
exit

:loserrr
@echo Text 2
exit
```

Also please don't upload a photo when asking a question